# Bulk checking http status codes without downloading the page

Tags: php, curl

I have around 10000 urls in my mysql database..  I would like to check whether those pages exists or not using php.

The point is I don't want to waste my bandwidth.

Is it possible to check only http status codes?

Here is my current curl code?

```
$http = curl_init($url);
$result = curl_exec($http);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($http);
echo $http_status;
```

Comment: Use get_headers function http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: Or do a `HEAD` request with curl, same diff probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following [cURL options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to make a `HEAD` request:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'HEAD',
```

You could also use:

```
CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
```

To have `curl_exec` return false whenever a erroneous HTTP code is returned.

If you have 10,000 URLs and this is a recurring task, you will probably want to look at `curl_multi_*` functions and process the URLs in batches of 4, 8 or something close to it. The speed-up is significant.

Comment: You answer was really helpful. Thanks Alex for your answer. I just learned about that curl_multi_* functions from you. Can you give me an example on how to use that in my http status check example.?

Comment: @Giri: I could, but my wrapper for cURL[Multi] alone is nearly 200 LOC  and it's pretty much tailored to my needs, posting a solution for your need here would make the answer much longer and wouldn't teach you anything (I don't comment code). Basically, you need to set up each handle as you normally would but instead of calling `curl_exec` you need to call a combination of `curl_multi_add_handle`, `curl_multi_exec`, `curl_multi_info_read` and `curl_multi_getcontent`. The comments on the PHP manual for these functions have lots of examples you can look into.

Comment: @Giri: Of course, StackOverflow as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl-multi+php.